# Don't want to use venv, but want to use virtualenv

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv, pyvenv

I want to do some experiments with tensorflow in virtualenv. I followed the tutorial and install tensorflow and virtualenv. Everything works well. However, when I try to use matplotlib.pylot. It said I need framework. So I follow the [solution][1] https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html. It said "If you are on Python 3, use venv instead of virtualenv"

```
python -m venv my-virtualenv
source my-virtualenv/bin/activate
```

Then I activate the virtual Environments, but all the module that I install in virtualenv cannot find. I think I just use venv, but not use virtualenv. Now I want to use virtualenv, and don't want to use venv any more. I even try to delete venv, but it seems it doesn't work. What should I do? How do I what virtual environments I am using? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you installed tensorflow before the step `source my-virtualenv/bin/activate`. Do it the other way around. After you activate the virtual env, install tensorflow.

Comment: No, I installed tensorflow after activate the virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

You've to install packages inside the virtual environment for them to be available to used when the virtual environment is activated. So, install the packages after activating the environment!

Comment: I have installed packages after activating.